# Error on multiple auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have tried to create multiple auth, but everytime i am getting:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in /Users/admin/www/laravelapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 123

Searched in google but nothing helped. Have no idea. May be someone got this error before? my auth.php in config:

```
<?php

return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
   ...
```

Cleared cache. But not helped. PS: i have used it before in another project but not worked in new one. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my GOD, i found the problem. Problem: providers name was wrong :/

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [ //<----- changed to admins like in guards 
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
   ...
```

Sometimes you need just post code to stackoverflow to see your own problem :)

Comment: really broth? xD

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz yep :D